# Projection of a plane on coordinate planes

Tags: determinant, coordinate-systems, 3d

$$\left|\begin{matrix} x & y & z & 1 \\ x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & 1 \\ x_3 & y_3 & z_3 & 1 \end{matrix}\right|=0$$

This is the equation of the plane that I have (in 3D). Now I need to find the area of projection of this plane on the $xy,yz$ and $zx$ planes (in the direction of positive axes only). How should I find it ?

Please give your answers in determinant form.

Please note: I just started learning 3d geometry today. So don't mind if my question is too silly :-P...

Comment: Yes I mean the determinant @HenningMakholm ...i don't know how to format determinants in LATEX...could you edit if possible...

Comment: Also, if the plane is not parallel to one of the axes, its projection on to either of the axis planes will be _all_ of the axis plane, whose area is infinite ...

Comment: x @Sanchayan: Even so, the projection can have infinite area in general.

Comment: Okay let me tell you the full problem....(x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2),(x3,y3,z3) are the vertices of the base of a tetrahedron.The fourth vertex is (x4,y4,z4).In my book they have found the area projection of the base of the tetrahedron on the coordinate planes as Axy,Axz,Ayz....now i guess you got me? @HenningMakholm

Comment: Its given like $A_{xy}=(1/2)\begin{vmatrix} x_{ 2 } & y_{ 2 } & 1 \\ x_{ 3 } & y_{ 3 } & 1 \\ x_4 & y_4 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$...which I can't derive...@HenningMakholm

Comment: @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a polygon in space and want to find its projection to a particular plane, what you do is project each of the vertices to that plane and draw the corresponding polygon there. You can then compute the *area* of the projection by working in the plane directly.

In the case of, for example, the $xy$-plane, the initial projection into that plane consists simply of throwing away the $z$ coordinates (you when you vary the $z$ coordinate, the point moves along a line parallel to the $z$-axis, and the $x$ and $y$ coordinates you already have describe the intersection of that line with the $xy$-plane).

The determinant $$\frac12\left|\begin{matrix}x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3 & y_3 & 1 \\ x_4 & y_4 & 1 \end{matrix}\right|$$ reduces to the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) for the area of a plane triangle when you expand it by minors along the last column. (Alternatively, it is probably possible with a bit of algebraic manipulation to show that it is equal to a determinant that represents the volume of a 3D parallelepiped where the original triangle is half of its basis and the height is $1$, but that doesn't sound very enlightening to me).

The original 4-by-4 determinant in the question is a systematic way to find an equation for the *infinite plane* that contains the three points $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$. An equation for that plane is, however, not directly useful if what you're interested in is the area of particular bounded subsets of it.